# I am trying to convert a javascript Number type to a BIGINT to be passed to a Postgres table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, bigint, math.js

I have a BIGINT I need to store in a Postgres table. I am using a rest API and have no issue passing in the javascript Number type on row creation but when I try and update it I get this error:

```
 "Error: invalid input syntax for integer: \"\"
```

Is there a way to cast this type? I tried using math.js with no luck so far. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see :

```
const string = 'YourNumberHere';
BigInt(string);
```

Using Math.js :

```
var reqId = "YourNumberHere";
var myBigNumber = math.bignumber(reqId);
var res = math.add(myBigNumber, 1);
console.log(myBigNumber.toString());
console.log(res.toString());
```

You can use a JavaScript lib called ***BigInteger.js*** for the purpose.it is an arbitrary-length integer library for Javascript, allows arithmetic operations on integers of unlimited size, notwithstanding memory and time limitations.This lib can be download from [this link](http://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js).

Like `var largeNumber = bigInt("75643564363473453456342378564387956906736546456235345");`

You can find documentation of this lib [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer)

Comment: thank you for the feedback! Unfortunately, I've tried both these approaches already and I still get the same message.